# Error : "Number of classes in y_true not equal to the number of columns in 'y_score'"

Tags: python, roc, multiclass-classification, imbalanced-data

i have an imbalanced multiclass dataset , when i try to compute the roc_auc_score i get this error: ValueError: Number of classes in y_true not equal to the number of columns in 'y_score'.

here is the code:

```
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_prob = model.predict_proba(X_test)
macro_roc_auc_ovr = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_prob, multi_class="ovr",
                              average="macro")
```

Any suggestions to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a great guide on how to ask good questions.  Spesicfically https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  having data the code and what you find the error to be

Comment: Welcome! What are the dimensions of `y_test` and `y_prob`? If they're `numpy` arrays, you should be able to call `y_test.shape` and `y_prob.shape`.

Comment: y_test.shape = (3661, 38) and y_prob.shape = (3661, 40)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution @nesrine-bn ?

Comment: No @Daniel Vilas-Boas, not yet

Comment: I may have found the answer. Can you take a look below @nesrine-bn ?

Answer (score 2):

This problem happened to me when I did not have at least one example of the class inside each fold. To solve I replaced KFold for StratifiedKFold.

I think it may be a problem with your split method. You can ask the split to be stratified as well passing stratify=y to the train_test_split method (if that's what you're using)

Comment: This is a patch on probably a bug. Imagine that we can't do stratifiedKFold ( time series setting), here, if you simply have imbalanced classes, there's no workaround...