# Number of classes in y_true not equal to the number of columns in 'y_score'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc, multiclass-classification

I am trying to built a predictive model for multiclass data. I have use the roc_auc_score for validation. When the data is split into validation and testing datasets and cross validated I am not facing an error. However, when the same dataset is cross validated using pso best parameters I am getting the above error.

```
#test train split
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 2021) 

X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_val, y_val, test_size = 0.5, random_state = 2021)
```

Fiting the dataset

````
# Fit SVM classifier
clf_pso = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True, C=para_pso.best_param['C'], gamma=para_pso.best_param['gamma'])
clf_pso.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('(Cross Validation) AUC Score:', np.mean(cross_val_score(estimator=clf_pso, X=X_train, y=y_train, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')))```

#Printing AUC score

print('(Test set) AUC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test, clf_pso.predict_proba(X_test), average = 'macro', multi_class = 'ovo'))
````

```
Output error: ValueError: Number of classes in y_true not equal to the number of columns in 'y_score'
```

The above error is in this line:

```
print('(Test set) AUC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test,  clf_default.predict_proba(X_test), average = 'macro', multi_class = 'ovo'))
```

For the below code the dataset gives no error

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=2021)

# Fit SVM classifier
clf_default = SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)
clf_default.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('(Cross Validation) AUC Score:', np.mean(cross_val_score(estimator=clf_default, X=X_train, y=y_train, cv=5, scoring = 'roc_auc')))

#Printing AUC score
print('(Test set) AUC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test,  clf_default.predict_proba(X_test), average = 'macro', multi_class = 'ovo'))
```

using `stratify=y` is also not working in both cases

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : "Number of classes in y\_true not equal to the number of columns in 'y\_score'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65325292/error-number-of-classes-in-y-true-not-equal-to-the-number-of-columns-in-y-sc)